# what is wrong with my code? it should output 0-9 but it failed to do so. I think the error is in go()

Tags: javascript

Can you help me debug this code? I can't see the errors in it. There is also no ouput to determine the error.

> ```
>  function go()
> {
>     var procedures = [];
>
>     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
>     {
>         procedures[procedures.length] = function () 
>         {
>             alert("You are now " + i + " years old");
>         } 
>         run_procs(procedures);
>     }
>
>     function run_procs(procs) 
>     {
>         for (var i = 0; i < procs.length; i++)
>         {
>             procs[i]();
>         }
>     }
>
>     go();
> }
> ```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

You have executed the function inside the function. Put `go();` outside.

Answer (score 1):

For ease I have commented inline some of the issues you have.

```
 function go()
 {
 var procedures = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
 {
     procedures[procedures.length] = function () 
     {
         alert("You are now " + i + " years old");
         //this function doesn't return anything, so you will never assign any values to procedures[procedures.length]
     } 
     run_procs(procedures);
 }

 function run_procs(procs) 
 {
     for (var i = 0; i < procs.length; i++)
     {
         procs[i]();
         //the argument you have passed to this function is not a function itself, so this won't do much.
     }
 }
 //this is inside the go() declaration so you aren't actually calling it. 
 go();
 }
```

None of this code ever gets run because you just declare the function and don't actually call it. Hence you aren't getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. you load the same point in the array again and again.
2. you call procs? what is procs?
3. go is inside go?

try the following fix:

```
var procedures = [];
function go()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
   {
       procedures[i] = function () 
       {
           alert("You are now " + i + " years old");
       }
       run_procs();
   }


}

function run_procs(procs)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < procedures.length; i++)
     {
         procedures[i]();
     }
 }

 go();
```

jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/n8FSe/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `go` inside `go` to create an indefinite recursion. You need to call the function `go` from outside the function to start execution of the function.

```
function go()
{
    var procedures = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        procedures[procedures.length] = function () 
        {
            console.log("You are now " + i + " years old");
        } 
        run_procs(procedures);
    }

    function run_procs(procs) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < procs.length; i++)
        {
            procs[i]();
        }
    }

}

go(); // <<-- this should be outside the function body
```